# Puppeteer js, unable to execute page in $$eval

Tags: puppeteer

I've seen this asked around but I can't pinpoint what I'm doing wrong.

> Error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: page is not defined

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://example.com');

const getAllElements = await page.$$eval('.aclass', links => {
  links.map(link => {
    page.hover(link);
    page.screenshot({path: `example${link}.png`});
  })
})
```

Expected behavior is that I go to example.com, I then get all the .aclass elements.  Return those as 'links" then I map over each link, which should give me each element in link.  I then am expecting to be able to page.hover and page.screenshot.  However this is where I get the error that page is not defined.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `$$eval()` executes in the page context not puppeteer. get the elements using `page.$$()`, iterate over those in puppeteer context instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `hover` and `screenshot` returns Promise.
2. Don't pass page to `page.$$eval`. Instead you can do the following:

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://example.com');

const getAllElements = await page.$$('.aclass');
for (let [i, link] of getAllElements.entries()) {
    await link.hover();
    await link.screenshot({path: `example${i}.png`});
}
```

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: JSHandles can be evaluated only in the context they were created! @mbit

Comment: @FabricioG my bad, edited the answer. `page.hover()` gets a selector not element. let me know if still not working.